# Openshift RHCOS 4.9-RHEL8.4 FirewallD

Tags: openshift, rhel, vcenter

I am building an OCP 4.9 deployment in my lab with RHCOS 4.9 for the control plane and RHEL 8.4 for the worker nodes on VCenter 6.7.

I am using RHEL 8.4 as the bastion host with Apache, HAProxy and the OCP install files, Bootstrap etc.

**Question #1** - Does anyone have the latest version of what the append-bootstrap.ign should look like as I heard the "append" is replaced with "merge" and the version is 3.2.0?

**Question #2** - Can the firewalld be disabled or is this required in RHEL 8.4 for OCP 4.9?

**Question #3** - If the firewalld is required, what should the configuration look like in addition to opening ports tcp ports 8080, 6443 and 22623

Thanks,

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.